# Did anyone ever heard about asciihex encoding?

Tags: soap, encoding, soapui, decoding

this type of encoding is used in soap messages...
I'm receiving a message encoded in ASCIIHEX and I don't have any ideas on how this encoding actually works although I have the clear description of the encoding method:

"If this mode is used, every single original byte is encoded as a sequence of two characters representing it in hexadecimal. So, if the original byte was 0x0a, the transmitted bytes are 0x30 and 0x41 (‘0’ and ‘a’ in ASCII)."

The buffer received : "1f8b0800000000000000a58e4d0ac2400c85f78277e811f2e665329975bbae500f2022dd2978ff95715ae82cdcf9415efec823c6710247582d5965c32c65aab0f5fc0a5204c415855e7c190ef61b34710bcdc7486d2bab8a7a4910d022d5e107d211ed345f2f37a103da2ddb1f619ab8acefe7fdb1beb6394998c7dfbde3dcac3acf3f399f3eeae152012e010000"

The actual file contains this : "63CD13C1697540000000662534034000030000120011084173878R           00000001000018600050000000100460000009404872101367219                    000000000000   DNSO_038114   000000002001160023Replacem000000333168625            N0000 00000000"

The provider sent me the file that contains the string above. I tried to start from the buffer string and get the same result as the one sent by the provider but no results. I also tried searching after this "asciihex" encoding and same. If someone knows anything about this encoding or can give me any advice I would really appreciate it. I have pretty much no experience with SOAP services.

[image: SOAPUI Request]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that content and buffer represent the same string? Definition says *"If this mode is used, every single original byte is encoded as a sequence of two characters representing it in hexadecimal"*. So this looks like a simple hex representation of bytes. But the strings don't match. The length is wrong, the patterns are wrong. For example, there are a bunch of zeros in the actual file that you can't see in the encoding. So either the examples are incorrect, or something else is going on. Can't you ask the provider for some source code to transform one into the other and vice-versa?

Comment: And one other thing. I see a `Compress` element in your request. Does that mean that the buffer can be a compressed file? Do you know what kind of a file it can be? Is it always text? A binary?

Comment: I've received a file named exactly as the one I'm trying to get in SOAPUI. Same docId, same everything. The file is named "CD13_C169754_RICEC150_4270590", they've also confirmed all of this. It's only a 500ish bytes file extension.

Comment: Most probably the compression might be the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments above, it's possible the buffer is compressed. It starts with `1F 8B` which is a signature for [GZIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) compression. See the following [list of signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures).

Write the bytes that correspond to the hex strings into a file. Name that file with a `gz` or `tar.gz` extension and try to extract it or open it with some file archiver tool.

Another thing you could try would be to not send the `Compress` element in your request, assuming it's an optional field and you can do that. If you can, check if the buffer changes and has the proper length and you can see similar patterns as the original content (for those zeros at the end, for example).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this as soon as I can and I'll come back with the results :D Really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm back, I tried to remove the compress argument from the call and now nothing is retrieved... As you said that file is a gzip, I added a screenshot of the file here and I hope this is hopefully useful information...